# Magento2: Need to get customer detail after guest checkout when enter the email

Tags: magento2, checkout, checkout-page

I need to get customer details(first name, last name so on) after guest checkout when submitting the email and without creating an account.

For more detail please check secreenshot:

[image]

After placing the order

[image]

Comment: Without creating an account ? How you can achieve this without account ? Do you mean without customer login here ?

Comment: I think you want customer account information when user enter their email, if that email exist in your system then you will get firstname, lastname and all other information otherwise not.

Comment: Is there any guest checkout event? After guest order success

Comment: Acutally at that time customer does not sync in magento admin

Comment: Your requirement is not clear, Can you please update your question with some more information ?

Comment: I just need guest checkout customer details after placing the order without creating an account.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100696/discussion-between-kishan-savaliya-and-shiwani).

Comment: take a look at `Magento/Sales/Model/order::getCustomerIsGuest` and write an observer with conditional and get order details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create `events.xml` file in your custom module here

> app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/events.xml

Here you need to add `checkout_submit_all_after` event like this..

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="checkout_submit_all_after"> <!-- sales_order_place_after -->
        <observer name="your_observer_name" instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\OrderPlaceAfter" />
    </event>
</config>
```

Now you need to create one observer file there you can get customer and order details.

> app/code/Vendor/Module/Observer/OrderPlaceAfter.php

Content for this file..

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

class OrderPlaceAfter implements ObserverInterface
{
    protected $logger;

    public function __construct(
        LoggerInterface $logger
    ) {
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }

    public function execute(Observer $observer){
        try {
            $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
            $customerFirstName = $order->getCustomerFirstname();
            $customerLastName = $order->getCustomerLastname();

            $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/guest_orders.log');
            $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
            $logger->addWriter($writer);
            $logger->info($customerFirstName);
            $logger->info($customerLastName);

            /*Here you can get all fields value which is available in `sales_order` table.*/

            return $observer;
        }catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->logger->info($e->getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Based on your requirement you can modify code in your observer.

Hope this will help you!

Comment: Thanks Kishan, I am working on this

Comment: Did you check this code? am getting error

Comment: What error you are getting?

Comment: 1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException): Requested entity doesn't exist

Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException): Requested entity doesn't exist

Comment: Yes @Shiwani, I've tested my code and that is working without any issues.

Comment: Did you check on chat?

Comment: I've updated my code with logger you will get log of you customer first and last name there.